# Kotlin with JPA/Hibernate: no lazy-loading without `open`?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, lazy-loading, kotlin

Most Kotlin JPA example code looks like this

```
class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) { /* ... */ }
```

or even

```
data class Person(val name: String="", val age: Int=0) { /* ... */ }
```

Now, the [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-pojo), and I think also several other ORMs, state that they usually want to create proxies or otherwise extend the model class, but to allow that in Kotlin the class has to be explicitly defined `open`. This is currently impossible with data classes and I assume, judging from my own experience, that most people don't think about it when writing JPA entities in Kotlin.

So, to come to my question (this is stackoverflow after all), is it enough to do

```
 open class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) { /* ... */ }
```

or would we actually have to do

```
 open class Person(open val name: String, open val age: Int) { /* ... */ }
```

to not needlessly hinder the ORM at doing its job properly?
If it really is harmful, we should probably propose to add a warning to IntelliJ IDEA, that if a class is has an `@Entity` annotation, it should be defined `open`.

Comment: I don't see how the word "harmful" is applicable here. Could you clarify its use or delete it from the question if it is not important?

Comment: Mainly it's the fact that at least Hibernate cannot lazy-load classes that are final or have final accessor methods and using data classes for JPA often looks like a good thing to do, but can actually hurt performance, because they are final by definition (at the moment at least; heard that may change). The title is very clickbaity, because I thought that should be something more universally known and to prevent e.g. applications ported to Kotlin having worse performance than the Java counterpart and users then blaming Kotlin :/

Comment: Thank you for paraphrasing the question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The tutorial you provided specifies:

> The entity class must have a public or protected no-argument constructor ... Interface may not be designated as an entity ... The entity class must not be final. No methods or persistent instance variables of the entity class may be final.

Kotlin classes follow the JavaBeans convention for setters/getters.

If your ORM has requirements as the above, then you indeed have to specify `open` on the class and its methods:

```
open class Person(open val name: String = "", 
                  open val age: Int = 0)
```

The default values for all of the constructor parameters allow Kotlin to generate an additional empty constructor. Alternatively you can provide it as a secondary constructor:

```
open class Person(open val name: String, open val age: Int) {
    constructor() : this("", 0)
}
```

Note that `open val` creates a private final field and an open getter. If that's not enough, use annotations like `@JvmField open val name`.

ORMs like the on you use have additional friction with Kotlin code because of the questionable design patterns they use (like making everything non-final).

A good option is to use a Kotlin-specific ORM. For example [Exposed](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed) is supported by JetBrains and used for some of its products, which speaks for itself. Another option is [Ebean](https://ebean-orm.github.io/) which officially supports Kotlin (thanks @johnp)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One of the things that struck me as odd was that final classes can't be lazy loaded in Hibernate and I imagined that could seriously hurt performance if not taken into consideration. I personally switched to [Ebean](https://ebean-orm.github.io/) a couple weeks ago, because it explicitly mentions Kotlin and has a lower entry barrier than Hibernate, but I haven't heard of Exposed yet and will definitely take a look at it.

Comment: Lazy loading means that Hibernate needs to load the data only when the getter is invoked for the first time. However, the getter is already implemented by a programmer (as a simple field read)! Hibernate thus needs to change the functionality of that method so that it polls the JDBC at call time. You can change a method by modifying the bytecode at compile phase, or by dynamically extending the class and overriding the setters.

Comment: If you are willing to consider a Kotlin-specific ORM, https://github.com/mvysny/vok-orm could be a good option. It still uses POJOs which may e.g. be annotated with JSR303 annotations and passed around to web forms; it uses Sql2o behind the scenes; it focuses on Kotlin as the sole target language. Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Answer (score 1):

The [kotlin allopen](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html) compiler plugin is probably worth mentioning here.

```xml
<pluginOptions>
    ...
    <option>all-open:annotation=javax.persistence.Entity</option>
</pluginOptions>
```

This will make all classes annotated `@Entity` open.